# immutable class objects

Tags: java, class, immutability

the first class is immutable class and i need to make the imm2 immutable class too,**my question is can i use objects of the imm class in imm2 class**??

```
final class imm{
 private final int value;

        public imm(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
}
final class imm2{

    imm value;  // is this legal ???

    public imm2(imm value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public imm getValue() {
        return value;
    }
   // set value removed is there any problems here i mean is my code correct now?

}
```

Comment: You can compile the program and find out.

Comment: You cannot extend 'imm' because that class is `final`. If you remove the `setValue` from `imm2`, then this class will be immutable, too.

Comment: if i remove the setValue it will be immutable but still having errors and im trying to find a way to create objects in the second class is there any way for it?

Comment: If you have errors, why haven't you mentioned them in the question?

Comment: `is there any problems here`.. yes, variable `value` is not `private`. Classes in the same package as class `imm2` can change that variable.

Comment: i don't have errors,just thought that intalizing the imm value in the second class is illegal but can compile

Comment: There are 2 ways to initialize the `imm` in an immutable `imm2` class. 1. In the variable declaration (i.e. `private final imm value = new imm(42);`), or 2. In the `imm2` constructor you can write `value = new imm(42);`. However it's not the fact that `imm2` isn't immutable that's bothering me (or I imagine the other people reading this) - it's the fact that it begins with a lower case letter!

Comment: yeah,sorry just forget i just voted..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can never `extend` a `final class`, but you can make objects of them.

Extending example;

```
class imm2 extends imm { } // Illegal, imm is final.
```

Creating new (instantiating);

```
imm yourImm = new imm(1); // Perfectly legal.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `imm2` class is not immutable, since it has a `setValue` method, that changes its state. Remove this method to make it immutable.

Comment: your right setValue removed,thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

well by defination

```
final class imm{
```

imm is not extendable..

Comment: That means i cannot make objects in the second class right??

Comment: @yazan - No. Extend, and instantiate (make new objects) are different.

Comment: you can create objects of imm in imm2. If you want to make imm2 immutable, then apply same rules that you applied for imm. final instance varibale, constructor, no setters etc..

Answer (score 1):

A class being final does not mean it is immutable, it just means you cannot extend it further. Whether it is immutable depends on how you define its behavior.

As `Eran` already mentioned `imm2` is not immutable since you are allowing users to change its internal state (but it is final and cannot be extended)